# How to dynamically set an image or use default

Tags: reactjs

I am mapping through objects and would like to dynamically add the image source, but if there is not an image, id like to load the default image. Ideally this take as little computational power as can be because there are lots of images that will change often..

I already have the dynamic image src setup, but i dont have the loop to check if it exists. Just wondering what the fastest way to do this is.

```
...
render() {
    const images = require.context("../../../../../public/images", true);
...

return {
{this.props.items.map...

<img src={images(`./${item.item}`)} />

....)}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom image component to handle this:

```
import React from 'react';

class Img extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      src: this.props.src,
      error: false,
    };

   this.onError = this.onError.bind(this);
  }

  onError = () => {
    if (!this.state.error) {
      this.setState({
        src: this.props.defaultSrc,
        error: true,
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    const { src } = this.state;

    return (
      <img
        src={src}
        onError={this.onError}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default Img;
```

And then you can set like this:

```
<Img src='if-this-image-not-exists-doesnt-matter.png' defaultSrc='https://picsum.photos/id/237/200/300' />
```

Comment: This is awesome thanks so much for your time! But it's still giving me an error Error: Cannot find module './imagenotthere.svg'

Comment: <Img
 src={images(`./${item.item}.svg`)}
defaultSrc={images("./default.png")}
/>

Answer (score 0):

If you mean that `item.item` might be null or nonexistent, you could simply OR it with the default: `item.item || default.png`.

If you mean item.item is present but may fail to load, you could set an `onError` handler on the image and set the arc to the default if it errors.

An alternate way to do the onError approach would be to set the src to the default image initially for all the `<img>` elements and instantiate an Image object to load item.item. If it succeeds, update the `<img>` accordingly. If it fails you’ve already got the fallback image.

Here's a fiddle showing how you could load a default image initially, load the real image, and display an error image if loading fails:

https://jsfiddle.net/rayhatfield/ouqyav7p/22/

Comment: thanks for your answer, when I try this, i still get an error saying the image (which doesnt exist) cant be found.        <img src={images(`./${item.item}` || "./default.png")} />

Comment: What does the output (the rendered markup) look like? Is the `src` attr what you expect it to be? Have you verified that `images(./${item.item}` is what you expect it to be?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `require.context`. Doing a require in a render function seems super sketchy to me. Is this running in a browser and trying to import the `public/images` directory at runtime? I don't see how that could work.

Comment: i needed to add .svg to item.item, but yes that is working, but when it cant find an image that doesnt exists, it breaks... I am using webpack and the require.context is ,e following another stackoverflow thread to get the images to be dynamic, is there a better way?

Comment: <img src={images(`./${item.item}.svg` || "./default.png")}/>

Comment: What is the value of `item.item`? Are you sure it lines up with one of the entries in `images`?

Comment: item.item is the string name of my object, i have a bunch of images that are titled the same as the item.item but not all of the item.item have an image created for it, so id like to display the default for those

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194280/discussion-between-ray-hatfield-and-eat-mangos).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Ray Hatfield, the following solves the problem.

```
function getImage(item) {
    try {
        return images(`./${item}.svg`);
    }
    catch (e) {
        return images('./default.png');
    }
}
```

and then:

```
<img src={getImage(item.item)} />
```